# Update from ios 6 to ios 8

Tags: ios

I have an iPad 4.  Still have ios 6.  Want apps I can't purchase since they require ios 7.  How much space am I losing to upgrade to current ios 8 version?

Answer (score 5):

You can see below the free space available with iOS 8 for each kind of devices :

[image]

**Edit :**

Table from http://www.techrepublic.com/article/lawsuit-against-apple-for-ios-storage-misrepresentation-get-the-facts/

Comment: Nice table! Where did you find it? Or did you create this on your own?

Comment: I remembered this article ;) http://www.techrepublic.com/article/lawsuit-against-apple-for-ios-storage-misrepresentation-get-the-facts/

Comment: I still need clarification.  With version 6.1.3, my 32G iPad shows capacity of 28.0.  So do I assume that means the ios is using 4.0?  Looking at the table you posted, ios 8 will use 3.4.  So am I misunderstanding something?From everything I've been reading online, each new update ends up being larger.  What I want to know is what my capacity will be after I have updated to ios 8.1.3.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i also have an ipad running ios 6 and i want to update it to Ios 8.4 
It's still updating right now through itunes on my laptop and not through air. It says here that it will take 1.67 GB and it takes 2-5hours of download, i hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

iOS 8 = 1.1GB
iOS 8 Installer Package = 4.6GB 
iOS 8 Install Package also = **ouch!**

iOS 8 requires 4.6GB when you do it over the air [not connected to your computer], it's greatly reduced when you do it from your computer. There are tutorials out there that can guide you through the process to limit the iOS 8 catastrophe you might have heard about. People had to delete apps, photos, music etc just to download the new iOS because it required 4.6GB of free space to download even though iOS8 isn't actually 4.6GB or even close to it.

So the question is relative, your not really losing space, although you kind of are losing space. You have to have a certain amount just to download to the device, but the ostracized disk space not taken up *after* the install can once again be used to hold your apps, music etc that you deleted prior to the download. The decompressed version of the update will be deleted once the process is complete.

My recommendation : Forego all of this plug it up to your computer download/install from iTunes.